# Regex - Find all unique strings excluding some patterns

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to find all unique strings in my JavaScript project. I'm using WebStorm to search for it and I have this in terms of my search:

`'.*' // any number of quoted characters`

This does get me all the strings in the project but I would like to exclude some and am not sure how to.

I get results like `import`s and `require`s which I would like to exclude:

`const _ = require('lodash');`
and
`import React from 'react';`

What could I enter for a search to exclude that from my results?

Comment: So, if you're looking for _lines_ with quoted items. `(?=.*'.*')`. Except those lines cannot contain require nor import. `(?!.*\b(?:require|import)\b)`

Comment: Combining them you'd get `/^(?=.*'.*?')(?!.*\b(?:require|import)\b).*?'(.*?)'/gm` where _m_ is multi-line mode. The quoted item is in capture group 1. Still flawed, it only gets the _first_ quoted item in the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the regex you posted in your answer `(?!require)(?!import)('.*')` works:

```js
const tests = [
  "const _ = require('lodash');",
  "import React from 'react';",
  "some other 'string'"
];


tests.forEach(test => {
  console.log(/(?!require)(?!import)('.*')/.test(test));
});
```

Negative lookbehind works:

```js
const tests = [
  "const _ = require('lodash');",
  "import React from 'react';",
  "some other 'string'"
];


tests.forEach(test => {
  console.log(/(?<!(require|import).*)'.+'/.test(test));
});
```

Caveat: I believe negative lookbehind is currently only supported in Chrome

Answer (score 1):

Tried negative lookahead like this: `(?!require)(?!import)('.*')`
and it seems to yield the results I want